# JSF 2 Composite Component doesn't update value with f:ajax

Tags: java, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm trying to implement a Composite Component in JSF 2, which will support the "change" ajax event.
The CC is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<composite:interface name="inputText">
    <composite:attribute name="label" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:attribute name="disabled" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="required" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="rendered" default="true" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" 
        targets="#{cc.clientId}:input" />
</composite:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.clientId}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.label}" for="input" />
        <h:inputText id="input" label="#{cc.attrs.label}" 
            value="#{cc.attrs.value}" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}" 
            required="#{cc.attrs.required}" />
        <h:message for="input" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Now, I'm trying to use it in the following form:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <input:inputText value="#{bean.value}" label="d1" id="d1">
        <f:ajax event="change" update="@this,d2,d3" />
    </input:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" id="d2">
         <f:ajax event="change" update="@this,d1,d3" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="d3" value="#{bean.value}" />
</h:form>
```

As far as I understand, if I change **d1**, d2 and d3 should display the value of d1, and if I change **d2**, both d1 and d3 should change accordingly as well.
The problem is that when I change the value in **d2**, it only reflects in d3, while d1 stays blank, and when I change **d2**, d1 and d2 stays blank.

I'm using Mojarra 2.0.2 (I couldn't manage to make 2.0.3 on Google App Engine, which is my AS). Do I miss something in the way composite components should be built? Or is it a bug in Mojarra 2.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<h:panelGroup id="#{cc.clientId}"
```

is incorrect.  `#{cc.clientId}` is the id of your component, which is the parent of that panelGroup.  Setting them to have the same ID is incorrect.  Give it an id like "`myComponentPanel`", and it will have the absolute id (when placed in the component tree) of "`#{cc.clientId}:myComponentPanel`".

I suspect if you correct this, your ajax behaviour will work.

Comment: Well, you are correct. Removing the "#{cc.clientId}" and setting it to "panel" solved it. Putting the cc.clientId in the panelGroup caused JSF to generate a wrong html id (the rendered html component didn't had the form id attached to it), and putting a static one instead solved it.

I find it odd that in an example in IBM's blog they are using that technique - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu-0610/

Comment: @Yonatan IBM actually used a div (not a JSF panelGroup) with its id set to `#{cc.clientId}`

Comment: [Here's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu0111/index.html#wrap) another IBM JSF fu article which gives more background on why you should use a `div` in composite components.